# Why was Jewish High Priest commanded to have a golden plate inscribed “Holiness to the Lord”?

Tags: exodus, temple, priests

Why did God ask the High Priest to have a golden plate with the inscription “Holiness to the Lord” on his mitre (Exodus 28:36)? Is there any significant meaning in this?

In Exodus 28:38 it says, “Aaron shall bear the iniquity committed in the holy things” and “they [gifts from the people of Israel] may be accepted before the LORD”.

The complete passage (Exodus 28:36-38) from the King James Version:

> And thou shalt make a plate of pure gold, and grave upon it, like the engravings of a signet, HOLINESS TO THE LORD. And thou shalt put it on a blue lace, that it may be upon the mitre; upon the forefront of the mitre it shall be. And it shall be upon Aaron's forehead, that Aaron may bear the iniquity of the holy things, which the children of Israel shall hallow in all their holy gifts; and it shall be always upon his forehead, that they may be accepted before the LORD.

Why does this Golden plate receive such impressive lines?

Comment: IMHO, this question is off topic because it has nothing to do with Christianity.

Comment: @brasshat I'm pretty sure Christianity in general views Exodus as Scripture, therefore, this question posted here is seeking a Christian perspective answer, compared to a Jewish one, for example.

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific purpose for every part of the Priest's attire, and that is most certainly true of the High Priest; since only he can ever enter the Holy of Holies, and then only once a year for the specific purpose of atoning for the sins of Israel.

It is worth noting that nearly all of Chapter 28 is devoted to describing only the High Priest's garments, and in meticulous detail.

> Exodus 28:33 through 38  And beneath upon the hem of it thou shalt make pomegranates of blue, and of purple, and of scarlet, round about the hem thereof; and bells of gold between them round about: 34  A golden bell and a pomegranate, a golden bell and a pomegranate, upon the hem of the robe round about. 35  And it shall be upon Aaron to minister: **and his sound shall be heard when he goeth in unto the holy place before the LORD, and when he cometh out, that he die not.** 36  And thou shalt make a plate of pure gold, and grave upon it, like the engravings of a signet, HOLINESS TO THE LORD. 37  And thou shalt put it on a blue lace, that it may be upon the mitre; upon the forefront of the mitre it shall be. 38  **And it shall be upon Aaron's forehead, that Aaron may bear the iniquity of the holy things,*** which the children of Israel shall hallow in all their holy gifts; and it shall be always upon his forehead, that they may be accepted before the LORD.

In the above passage notice that there are two items that are designated with a specific purpose, that being the bells at the bottom of his robe and the plate.

1. the bells are to announce the identity of who is entering so that the ire of God is not unleashed, and he be killed.
2. The plate that identifies him as the bearer of the sins of Israel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And the purpose of bearing the sins of Israel is to take them before God in the Holy of Holies to be atoned for.

Comment: @Bye. Please check your translation. The King James leaves out the word 'committed' that you will see in the question. The Good News Bible partly offers an explanation in that they say that the offerings will be accepted even if the rites were not carried out to perfection. A fuller explanation is that the High Priest accepts responsibility for all the mistakes.

Comment: @gideonmarx Either you or I am misreading Scripture. As I read this it means the High Priest carries the sins of Israel into the Most Holy once a year for atonement. Much  of my reasoning is from: Exodus 30:10, Leviticus 16:32, 33, and 34. If I am the one misreading, could you backup your interpretation with Scriptures, as that will help my understanding of the Scriptures greatly.

Comment: The translation that includes 'committed' changes the meaning completely. The Good News Bible says in verse 38: 'I the Lord, will accept all the offerings that the Israelites dedicate to me, even if the people commit some error in offering them.' In other words, God knows what is in our hearts and even if we slip in a matter of procedure, He will still accept our prayers. The verses in Exodus and Leviticus are not applicable. This is about the direct communication between a person and God. The mistakes that are made are the responsibility of the High Priest for not teaching procedure properly.

Comment: @gideonmarx According my Southern Baptist upbringing you sure do have some strange understandings of Scripture.

Comment: @Bye. Strange maybe - but wonderful. Think about it. God says, I can see in your heart and even if you do not know how to pray properly, I will listen to you.

Comment: @Bye. This is a very important point in Christianity. One example. The Jews of the Galilee and from other countries pronounced Hebrew strangely. The Pharisees insisted that they cannot read in the Temple. That meant that they could not Bar Mitzvah. That meant that they could not be Jews. That meant that their bodies after death was burnt in 'hell'. This verse says that this is nonsense. The High Priest is responsible. Jesus says that it is nonsense. He also takes responsibility. That is Christianity. Down to earth real stuff, that is in front of your eyes, and easy to understand. And its cool.

Comment: @gideonmarx Your assertion is nonsense are you asserting that *Luke 4:16 and 17 KJV  And he came to Nazareth, where he had been brought up: and, as his custom was, he went into the synagogue on the sabbath day, and stood up for to read. And there was delivered unto him the book of the prophet Esaias. And when he had opened the book, he found the place where it was written,* are not true?

Comment: @gideonmarx and are you accusing Paul of heresy in 1Corinthians 2:6 and 7 KJV  *Howbeit we speak wisdom among them that are perfect: yet not the wisdom of this world, nor of the princes of this world, that come to nought: 7  But we speak the wisdom of God in a mystery, even the hidden wisdom, which God ordained before the world unto our glory:* ?? Faith itself is based on what we cannot see, touch, smell, or taste and without faith we are all doomed.

Comment: @Bye. I cannot communicate in chat. Some sort of block. Is the correct translation 'faith' or 'faithful'? Luke 4: 16 means what? Jesus was a ... that had studied at a ..... in ... .

Comment: @gideonmarx This will be my last on this subject. Faith is correct based on John 3:16 and Luke 4:16 falsifies your claim that they did not read in the Synagogue.